# SQL Challenge/Puzzle: Given a stack trace - How to find the top element at each point in time?

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, hive, teradata

- My real life use-case was to [merge nested ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40021020/sql-challenge-puzzle-how-to-merge-nested-ranges).
  I've drew some sketches and then I saw the resemblance between ranges starting and ending to stack PUSH and POP operations. I understood that solving this problem will also solve the original problem.

---

- The **op** column can actually be removed from the question. When val is NULL then it is a POP operation otherwise it is a PUSH operation.

---

## The Puzzle

A table, **stack_trace** ,contains the following columns:

- i    - Integer value that represents a point in time.
- op   - 2 possible operations: **I** ("in"/"push") and **O** ("out"/"pop").
- val  - The value inserted by the "in"/"push" operation or NULL for "out"/"pop" operation.

  The goal is to find what was the value at the top of the stack, at each point in time (**i**).

e.g.

(NULL values are represented here as empty spaces)

**data:**

```
i   op  val 
--  --  --  
1   I   A   
2   I   B   
3   O
4   I   C
5   O    
6   O
```

**required result:**

```
i   top_of_stack_val
--  ----------------
1   A
2   B
3   A
4   C
5   A
6
```

## Requirements

- The solution should be a single SQL query (sub-queries are fine).
- Only the following clauses are allowed: **SELECT**, **FROM**, **WHERE**, **GROUP BY**, **HAVING**, **ORDER BY**.
- The use of **WITH** clause (CTE - Common Table Expression) **is not allowed**.
- The use of T-SQL, PL/SQL etc. **is not allowed**.
- The use of UDF (User Defined Functions) **is not allowed**.
- The use of variables **is not allowed**.

## Sample data

```
create table stack_trace
(
    i       int
   ,op      char(1)
   ,val     char(1)
)
;

insert into stack_trace (i,op,val) values (1,'I','A');
insert into stack_trace (i,op,val) values (2,'I','B');
insert into stack_trace (i,op,val) values (3,'I','C');
insert into stack_trace (i,op,val) values (4,'I','D');
insert into stack_trace (i,op,val) values (5,'I','E');
insert into stack_trace (i,op)     values (6,'O');
insert into stack_trace (i,op)     values (7,'O');
insert into stack_trace (i,op)     values (8,'O');
insert into stack_trace (i,op,val) values (9,'I','F');
insert into stack_trace (i,op)     values (10,'O');
insert into stack_trace (i,op,val) values (11,'I','G');
insert into stack_trace (i,op,val) values (12,'I','H');
insert into stack_trace (i,op)     values (13,'O');
insert into stack_trace (i,op)     values (14,'O');
insert into stack_trace (i,op,val) values (15,'I','I');
insert into stack_trace (i,op,val) values (16,'I','J');
insert into stack_trace (i,op,val) values (17,'I','K');
insert into stack_trace (i,op,val) values (18,'I','L');
insert into stack_trace (i,op,val) values (19,'I','M');
insert into stack_trace (i,op)     values (20,'O');
insert into stack_trace (i,op,val) values (21,'I','N');
insert into stack_trace (i,op)     values (22,'O');
insert into stack_trace (i,op,val) values (23,'I','O');
insert into stack_trace (i,op)     values (24,'O');
insert into stack_trace (i,op,val) values (25,'I','P');
insert into stack_trace (i,op)     values (26,'O');
insert into stack_trace (i,op)     values (27,'O');
insert into stack_trace (i,op,val) values (28,'I','Q');
insert into stack_trace (i,op,val) values (29,'I','R');
insert into stack_trace (i,op)     values (30,'O');
insert into stack_trace (i,op)     values (31,'O');
insert into stack_trace (i,op)     values (32,'O');
insert into stack_trace (i,op)     values (33,'O');
insert into stack_trace (i,op)     values (34,'O');
insert into stack_trace (i,op)     values (35,'O');
insert into stack_trace (i,op,val) values (36,'I','S');
insert into stack_trace (i,op)     values (37,'O');
insert into stack_trace (i,op)     values (38,'O');
insert into stack_trace (i,op,val) values (39,'I','T');
insert into stack_trace (i,op,val) values (40,'I','U');
insert into stack_trace (i,op)     values (41,'O');
insert into stack_trace (i,op,val) values (42,'I','V');
insert into stack_trace (i,op,val) values (43,'I','W');
insert into stack_trace (i,op,val) values (44,'I','X');
insert into stack_trace (i,op)     values (45,'O');
insert into stack_trace (i,op)     values (46,'O');
insert into stack_trace (i,op,val) values (47,'I','Y');
insert into stack_trace (i,op)     values (48,'O');
insert into stack_trace (i,op)     values (49,'O');
insert into stack_trace (i,op,val) values (50,'I','Z');
insert into stack_trace (i,op)     values (51,'O');
insert into stack_trace (i,op)     values (52,'O');
```

## Required results

```
i   top_of_stack_val
--  ----------------
1   A
2   B
3   C
4   D
5   E
6   D
7   C
8   B
9   F
10  B
11  G
12  H
13  G
14  B
15  I
16  J
17  K
18  L
19  M
20  L
21  N
22  L
23  O
24  L
25  P
26  L
27  K
28  Q
29  R
30  Q
31  K
32  J
33  I
34  B
35  A
36  S
37  A
38  
39  T
40  U
41  T
42  V
43  W
44  X
45  W
46  V
47  Y
48  V
49  T
50  Z
51  T
52
```

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag the question with the database you are actually using.

Comment: Gordon, *These are* the databases I'm using and actually I've forgot to add Teradata.

Comment: @MT0 this is actually one of my favorites

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally I doubt that you will end up finding SQL that you can just use in all of SQL Server, Teradata, Postgres, and Oracle and that has acceptable performance if the table is at all large.

A SQL Server solution ([demo](http://rextester.com/SMW81388)) would be as follows

```
SELECT i,
       SUBSTRING(MAX(FORMAT(i, 'D10') + val) OVER (PARTITION BY Pos ORDER BY i 
                                                     ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING), 11, 8000)
FROM   (SELECT st.*,
               sum(CASE WHEN op = 'I' THEN 1 ELSE -1 END) 
                  OVER (ORDER BY i ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS pos
        FROM   stack_trace st) t1
ORDER  BY i;
```

Comment: This OVER logic should work for all four DBMSes, it's just the minor things (`SUBSTRING` & `+`) which need modified syntax :-)

Comment: @dnoeth - yep and the string padding with `FORMAT`

Comment: Yep. Any reason to add the 3rd parameter for SUBSTRING (8000)?

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz SQL Server requires you to tell it the length of the substring needed. We want everything from the 11th character onwards as the first 10 chars are the padded `i` value. A value of `1` would be sufficient for your example data but making it longer means it will continue to work if longer vals are popped on the stack.

Comment: I forgot that SQL Server doesn't have 2 parameters SUBSTRING

Comment: @MartinSmith, you are invited to check my generic solution

Comment: The idea is right (trying to attach `i` to `val` to take the max over the result). However, the solution should be "generic" - it should work for a stack of values of any data type. Concatenating `i` and `val` as done here depends on implicit conversion to string, and - worse - conversion back from string to the original data type of `val` (which probably won't work in any DB product).

Comment: @mathguy - Working with any datatype without customization might be a desirable feature but it certainly isn't required. The question asks about a table with a specific schema.

Answer (score 4):

This is a nice puzzle.

As my main DBMS is Teradata I wrote a solution for it using Analytical functions (needs TD14.10+):

```
SELECT dt.*,
   -- find the last item in the stack with the same position
   Last_Value(val IGNORE NULLS)
   Over (PARTITION BY pos
         ORDER BY i) AS top_of_stack_val
FROM 
 ( 
   SELECT st.*,
      -- calculate the number of items in the stack
      Sum(CASE WHEN op = 'I' THEN 1 ELSE -1 end) 
      Over (ORDER BY i
            ROWS Unbounded Preceding) AS pos
   FROM stack_trace AS st
 ) AS dt;
```

This solution works for Oracle, too, but PostgreSQL & SQL Server don't support the `IGNORE NULLS` option for `LAST_VALUE` and emulating it is quite complicated, e.g see Itzk Ben-Gan's [The Last non NULL Puzzle](http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/last-non-null-puzzle)

Edit: In fact it's not that complex, I forgot Itzik's 2nd solution, the old piggyback trick ;-)

Martin Smith's approach will work for all four DBMSes.

Comment: Was able to simplify my answer quite a lot off the back of this +1

Comment: Dieter, the man and the legend :-) Thank you for your work on the Teradata forums. BTW, There's another solution for Teradata that uses a patented syntax. Would you like to give it a shot?

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz: I try to avoid `RESET WHEN` :-) Of course it simplifies a query (one instead of two or three levels of OLAP functions), but the plan is exactly the same. If you only need a single OLAP it's ok, otherwise additional OLAP functions can be usually added to an existing level without a new step in Explain.

Answer (score 2):

Although it does require an additional step -

## Generic solution for **Hive**, **Teradata**, **Oracle**, **SQL Server** and **PostgreSQL**

```
select      s.i

           ,min (s.val) over
            (
                partition by    s.depth
                               ,s.depth_val_seq
            )                                   as top_of_stack_val            

from       (select      s.i
                       ,s.val
                       ,s.depth
                        
                       ,count (s.val) over 
                        (
                            partition by    s.depth
                            order by        s.i
                            rows            between unbounded preceding and current row
                        )                                                                   as depth_val_seq
                         
            from       (select      s.i
                                   ,s.val
                                    
                                   ,sum (case s.op when 'I' then 1 else -1 end)   over
                                    (
                                        order by        s.i
                                        rows            between unbounded preceding and current row
                                    )                                                                   as depth
             
                        from        stack_trace s
                        )
                        s
            )
            s
 
order by    i
;
```

Comment: Nice. Using the `depth_val_seq` to group together the push-on row with its corresponding pop-off row is pretty clever.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually an interesting problem.  What I would do is keep track of each elements position in the stack.  You can do this using a cumulative sum:

```
select st.*,
       sum(case when op = 'I' then 1 else -1 end) over (order by i) as pos
from stack_trace st;
```

Alas, at this point, I think you need a rather complicated join or subquery to figure out the most recent value that `pos` refers to.  Here is one method:

```
with st as (
      select st.*,
             sum(case when op = 'I' then 1 else -1 end) over (order by i) as pos
      from stack_trace st
     )
select st.*,
       (select val
        from st st2
        where st2.i <= st.id and st2.pos = st.pos and
              st2.val is not null
        order by i desc
        fetch first 1 row only
       ) as top_of_stack_val
from st;
```

Comment: Nice :-) Would you like to give it a try and solve it while referring to the base table only once?

Comment: BTW, you forgot to use the *pos* column :-)

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz . . . That's funny.  It is used in the subquery with equality.

Comment: My bad, I haven't seen the whole line

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz . . . I'm sorry.  I meant that I had left it out.  Thank you for observing that.  The right place is in the subquery where the code has now been fixed.  By the way, this is a good problem.

Answer (score 0):

## Teradata

```
select      s.i

           ,first_value (s.val) over 
            (
                partition by    s.depth
                order by        s.i
                reset when      s.op = 'I'
            )                                as top_of_stack_val

from       (select      s.i
                       ,s.val
                       ,s.op

                       ,sum (case s.op when 'I' then 1 else -1 end)   over
                        (
                            order by        s.i
                            rows            unbounded preceding
                        )                                                   as depth

            from        stack_trace s
            )
            s
            
order by    i
;
```

Comment: When you use `MIN` instead of `FIRST_VALUE` it will run in pre-TD14.10. But Explain will show the same three STAT-steps as your generic solution. `LAST_VALUE` only needs two STAT-steps :-)

Comment: @dnoeth **LAST_VALUE** was my first choice too. the **RESET** solution is just for fun. The extra **STAT** step is quite surprising here since the reset is done on a scalar and not on additional analytic function. It seems like a sub-optimal implementation of the optimizer.

Comment: You'll never find a better plan using `RESET WHEN`, it's always the same as the manual two or three level nested OLAP (like `CASE` vs. `COALESCE`, just a simplyfied syntax). If there are two functions with the same window the plan might be even worse. When the syntax was implemented in 13.10 I testet it a lot and was quite disappointed.

Comment: @dnoth, few years ago I've opened ER suggesting executing multiple **RESET WHEN** clauses with the same window definition in a single step :-)