# SQL Challenge/Puzzle: How to convert ASCII art ranges to relational data?

Tags: sql, regex, teradata, ascii-art

- The motivation for this challenge was to easily and accurately simulate a data set of IP ranges that relate to each other in a certain way.

---

## The Challenge

A table contains a single column of text type. 
The text contains one or more lines where each lines contains one or more sections created from dashes.
The goal is to write a query that returns a tuple for each section with its start point and end point.

E.g.

```
'
--- -- -
 ----
'
```

- The text above contains 2 lines.
- It contains 4 sections.
- The 1st line contains 3 sections.
- The 2nd line contains 1 section.
- The tuples for the 1st lines are (1,3),(5,6),(8,8).
- The tuple for the 2nd line is (2,5).

## Requirements

- The solution should be a single SQL query (sub-queries are fine).
- The use of T-SQL, PL/SQL etc. **is not allowed**.
- The use of UDF (User Defined Functions) **is not allowed**
- If needed, we might assume that there is only a single record in the table.

## Sample Data

```
create table t (txt varchar (1000) not null);

insert into t (txt) values 
(
'
 --- ---  ---   ---
----------          -
 - - -- -- --- ---
      ----- ---- --- -- -
   -------
' 
);
```

## Requested Result

* Only the last 2 columns (section_start/end) are required, the rest are for debugging purposes.

```
line_ind    section_ind section_length  section_start   section_end
--------    ----------- --------------  -------------   -----------
1           1           3               2               4
1           2           3               6               8
1           3           3               11              13
1           4           3               17              19
2           1           10              1               10
2           2           1               21              21
3           1           1               2               2
3           2           1               4               4
3           3           2               6               7
3           4           2               9               10
3           5           3               12              14
3           6           3               16              18
4           1           5               7               11
4           2           4               13              16
4           3           3               18              20
4           4           2               22              23
4           5           1               25              25
5           1           7               4               10
```

Comment: You should delete and post it here instead: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This challenge is a based on on a real life challenge I dealt with in work. it is  posted here because it has both practical value and learning value. I could have posted it as a Q&A but posting it as a challenge encourages others to present their own versions and insights.

Comment: Although some of you apparently don't like the concept of puzzles/challenges please keep in mind that others do. If you'll take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39936479/sql-puzzle-given-a-stack-trace-how-to-find-the-top-element-at-each-point-in-t you'll see that Gordon Linoff and Martin Smith, stackoverflow legends, quite enjoy it.

Comment: I can see why such challenges are fun when using a programming language and the other challenge you posted is indeed interesting, too. But this one seems like a huge pain in the ass to me, no offense. A challenge is fine as long as the challenge is not to use the least reasonable/adequate tool for a certain task.

Comment: @fancyPants, If you're working with MySQL you can feel free to skip this challenge. Unlike the other challenges I presented till now, the solution is really provider dependent and it is much more straight forward on some of the other databases (However, I really like the concept  of the challenge and I find it very useful for the creation of sample data sets)

Comment: Indeed I can only speak from a MySQL perspective. Should have mentioned that.

Answer (score 0):

## Teradata

```
with        l
            as
            (
                select      line_ind
                           ,line
                   
                from        table
                            (
                                regexp_split_to_table (-1,t.txt,'\r','')
                                returns (minus_one int,line_ind int,line varchar(1000))
                            )   
                            as l
            )
              
select      l.line_ind
           ,s.section_ind                                           
           ,regexp_instr    (l.line,'\S+',1,s.section_ind,0)        as section_start
           ,regexp_instr    (l.line,'\S+',1,s.section_ind,1) - 1    as section_end
           ,char_length     (s.section)                             as section_length
 
from        table
            (
                regexp_split_to_table (l.line_ind,l.line,'\s+','')
                returns (line_ind int,section_ind int,section varchar(1000))
            )  
            as s
           ,l
          
where       l.line_ind  =
            s.line_ind
            
order by    l.line_ind
           ,s.section_ind   
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Oracle

```
 SELECT row_n AS line_ind 
   ,dense_rank() over(PARTITION BY row_n ORDER BY s_beg) AS section_ind 
   ,s_end - s_beg AS section_length   
   ,s_beg - decode(row_n, 0, 0, instr(a,chr(10),1,row_n))  AS section_start   
   ,s_end - decode(row_n, 0, 0, instr(a,chr(10),1,row_n)) -1  AS section_end 
  FROM   (SELECT a 
           ,s_beg 
           ,DECODE(s_end, 0, length(a) + 1, s_end) AS s_end 
           ,length(substr(a, 1, s_beg)) 
              - length(REPLACE(substr(a, 1, s_beg), chr(10))) AS row_n 
           ,lvl 
     FROM   (SELECT txt as a 
                   ,DECODE(LEVEL, 1, 0, regexp_instr(txt , '\s|\n', 1, LEVEL - 1)) + 1 AS s_beg 
                   ,regexp_instr(txt , '\s|\n', 1, LEVEL) AS s_end 
                   ,LEVEL AS lvl 
             FROM   t 
             CONNECT BY LEVEL <= length(txt ) - length(regexp_replace(txt , '\s|\n')) + 1) 
     )WHERE  s_beg != s_end;
```

Comment: Hi Michael. Please compare your results to the requested results.

Comment: Hi Dudu. Thank you. I fixed id.

Answer (score 0):

## Oracle

```
select      regexp_instr (txt,'-+',1,level,0)       - instr (txt,chr(10),regexp_instr (txt,'-+',1,level,0) - length (txt) - 1,1)   as section_start
           ,regexp_instr (txt,'-+',1,level,1) - 1   - instr (txt,chr(10),regexp_instr (txt,'-+',1,level,0) - length (txt) - 1,1)   as section_end

from        t
                        
connect by  level <= regexp_count (txt,'-+')
;
```